# How dangerous is Django's built in test server when run remotely?

Tags: django, security, nginx

Concerning the built in debugging server started with the `manage.py runserver` command, the Django docs state, "DON’T use this server in anything resembling a production environment."

If I wanted to develop a Django application over ssh on a remote machine, would using Nginx as a proxy to a running Django debug server be a reasonable thing to do?  Is the Django debug server insecure, or just not built to handle large amounts of traffic?

Comment: If you don't want to use a server like Nginx or Apache, why not use a Python server like gunicorn? It's really simple to set up, and documented in Django's official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#runserver-port-or-address-port):

> DO NOT USE THIS SERVER IN A PRODUCTION SETTING. It has not gone through security audits or performance tests. (And that's how it's gonna stay. We're in the business of making Web frameworks, not Web servers, so improving this server to be able to handle a production environment is outside the scope of Django.)

So, that answers the latter two questions. As for the former, it depends on how your debug server is set up. If your server is exposed to the public Internet, doesn't have a firewall blocking port 8000, and you intend to use `runserver` with something other than the default 127.0.0.1 address, set up a more 'proper' application stack.

If you're going to use nginx, why not just use the [suggested FastCGI configuration](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/ServerArrangements#nginx) so that your debug environment will be more similar to the future production environment?

Answer (score 4):

Modern web servers have all sorts of features, related to both security and performance, that the Django development server does not. It is a stripped-down, very basic, single-threaded server for the purposes of development. Hence why the docs say to not use it in a production setting.

However, people get way to afraid of this statement. The key defining point is that it's for *development*. Whether that development takes place on your local machine or a remote VPS or an entire cluster is besides the point.

If the server is publicly available, it will be open to hacking, breaches, DoS attacks, etc. But, if what's there isn't of any importance, just a development site running on dummy data, it doesn't matter. So, yes, you can use the development server on your remote server for development purposes. There's nothing at all wrong with that. My only caution would be to avoid using production data (such as using a dump from your production database to develop against) because that data could be compromised. Otherwise, it's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the Django debug server insecure, or just not built to handle large amounts of traffic?

IT IS BOTH INSECURE AND NOT INTENDED FOR HEAVY TRAFFIC!

It might take care of a few of the issues by hiding the testing server behind a proxy, but if you're going to that much trouble you've done about the same amount of work as you need to do it right... right being WSGI. Use mod_wsgi, gunicorn, or check this out for more bleeding-edge solution: http://bartek.im/blog/2012/07/08/simplicity-nginx-uwsgi-deployment.html. Whatever you do.... DON'T USE THE DJANGO TEST SERVER FOR PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENTS!